# OSRM Routing in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, open-source-routing-machine

I'd like to implement routing on my map using OSRM and Openlayers 3 but there don't seem to be any examples or tutorials anywhere. Everyone seems to be utilising Leaflet for this as there is a plugin available.

I understand that I would need to add a layer to hold the geometry and then make a request to viaRoute on the routing server but I'm not sure what form this request should take. I know it requires parameters to be passed in the request in this format:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=52.503033,13.420526&loc=52.516582,13.429290&instructions=true
```

My javascript is still a little patchy so I'm not sure how to construct the request and response to be passed to my geometry layer.

Can anyone provide an example of this or perhaps give some guidance as to how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get your route response (this is an encoded polyline) add it like so:

```
// route is ol.geom.LineString
var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
    factor: 1e6
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
var feature = new ol.Feature(route);
feature.setStyle(styles.route);
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/

Comment: Orsm as ever Jonatas! This is exactly what I was looking for and I suspected that the returned JSON would be pushed onto a feature as geometries but there's no way I would have figured out the Polyline specifics. Thanks so much, I now have a way to build on this and return directions to the user! ;)

Comment: @JonatasWalker the fiddle works fine for two points. if I have multiple way points, what should I do ?

Comment: @KcYoosuf Just add some more logic, see [updated fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/).

Comment: I have managed to work thins perfectly using the fiddle. In my application all the lat-long values are from database fro showing a specific bus route. My question is, how can I disable displaying of alternate routes in OSRM

Comment: @KcYoosuf maybe you create a new question with all the details.

Comment: @JonatasWalker Please take a look at this question 

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192394/generating-a-route-from-an-array-of-lat-long-values-in-openlayers-3

Comment: @dvmac01 How dit you manage to add the driving instructions and show them on the screen?

Comment: @JonatasWalker
How is it possible to change the example so only the first point is created after clicking on the map and the second point is coming from the coordinates of features?

Comment: @niels I guess it's better you create a new question with its own complexity.

Comment: The provided jsfiddle does not work for me, and the following does not return promise `utils.getNearest(evt.coordinate).then..`

Comment: It works for me @allenhwkim, are you using a modern browser?

Comment: @JonatasWalker it was the problem of OSRM demo server, it's not guaranteed to work ever day and every time.